# convert any image type to RGB using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an image I get it using this code

```
[path,user_cance]=imgetfile();
im=imread(path);
```

Now I don't know if this image is RGB or indexed or ...

How to convert im to RGB for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Mathworks documentation (http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/imread.html), `imread` can infer the data type from its content.

You could do test if the colormap exists or is empty :

```
[im, map] = imread(path_to_image);
if(isempty(map)) % image is RGB or grayscale
    if(size(im, 3) == 1) % image is grayscale
        im = cat(3, img, img, img);
    end
else % image is indexed
    im = ind2rgb(im, map);
end
% now 'im' is a RGB-image
```

Comment: thak you very much .... can you write me a code for the same question BUT indexed status ?

I am a matlab beginner (:

Answer (score 2):

If it is indexed image you can easily use ind2rgb function:

read the image:

```
[X,map] = imread('imagefile.tif');
```

Verify that the colormap, map, is not empty, and convert the data in X to RGB.

```
if ~isempty(map)
    Im = ind2rgb(X,map);
end
```

finally you can View the size and class of **X**.

```
whos Im
```

**ind2rgb** converts the matrix **X** and corresponding **colormap** map to **RGB** (truecolor) format.
**X** can be of class uint8, uint16, single, or double. **RGB** is an m-by-n-by-3 array of class double.

[here](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) you can find the image formats that you can read using MATLAB.